# How to turn a Wordpress site to be responsive

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

By Simple curiosity purpose: Suppose we have a WordPress theme that is not responsive and we want to apply changes for it to become responsive.

How do I get started?
Do I Install bootstrap? Or without bootstrap and try each element to make it responsive?

I want to know how it is easier, faster and more professional.

Also I want to know and what tools you use (free) when you change WordPress themes.

Comment: I have requested that this post be closed as it is too broad. If you are interested in RWD (responsive web design) then I suggest you just [search for it onlone](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+make+a+responsive+website), there's tons of resources available. If you want to know how to make a responsive theme for wordpress, many of the principles of responsive design are independent of any back end implementation.

Comment: Consider starting with a Bootstrap based theme, then dropping in your current look and feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From past experience, 
 client want to retain existing theme(non-responsive theme), 
the solution was used https://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/
then install additional responsive theme(may it own dev or purchase) with the plugin to cater the client's need.

If no need to retain existing theme, 
you may start with bootstrap or other responsive theme.